# Java on Linux - open file manager

Tags: java, linux, javafx, sh

I'm developing a JavaFX application for both Windows and Linux (Debian/Ubuntu distributions), currently on Linux Mint (I honestly don't have any experience with other distros than Mint). The application should be able to open folders with the system's file manager.

While on Windows I use this with no problems:

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(path);
```

This doesn't seem to work on Linux, so I thought of simply using Bash commands like:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "nemo " + path);
```

But this only works on Linux Mint Cinnamon, since KDE and other editions may come with different "default" file managers (like Dolphin or Nautilus).

Now is there a way, either programmatically with Java or with Bash, to get the associated file manager?

Comment: I know on Mac, you can run `open path`, and that brings up the file manager

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. It gives me the following output: ``Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console``

Comment: You can use "xdg-open" for all linux distros. xdg-open one of [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/)

Comment: @MehmetSunkur awesome, that's what I needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the default file manager.
You can use the `xdg-mime` command for that.

`xdg-mime query default inode/directory` return the default file manager.

Output if it's dolphin : `dolphin.desktop`

OR

`xdg-open <directory>` but it can start the wrong file manager sometimes.

See the [documentation](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html) for more.

---

**`xdg-open <directory>` has been deprecated**

use `'gio open'` instead. see [source](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1473#issuecomment-303656214)

Comment: "xdg-open <directory> has been deprecated"  

According to the provided source xdg-open is and was actually not deprecated  
(it was a bug that it appeared to be deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

you have to double think things... what is for you *to open a folder* ??? What does it mean?  different operating systems (like windows, mac, or the like) have different file managers, so the mechanisms are subject to differences (mostly as they have evolved from previous environments, sharing nothing in common and without java in mind).  Even there are operating systems with no file manager at all, as for example linux console applications don't assume a desktop is running at all and cannot call the file manager to open a window (where? no windows at all, only the black console screen) and show the files contained there.

Windows applications user the file Explorer to show folder contents and the communication with the explorer follows a path that doesn't share anything in common (while the mechanism is similar, anyway) with the one used in linux.

In linux you have the added problem that there are several (better said, many) desktop environments competing and doing things differently between each other.

The java support doesn't dig so deep in the desktop environment to allow for the task you face on in a desktop environment independent way.

Anyway, there are several file managers written in java that do the same and can be run in either environment (java, windows and the mac), so you can run other route, and use a common file manager for the task.  And probably communicating with a program written in java is easier from your application.

Comment: Isn't that all clear from my entry post? I said I'm developing for Windows and some Linux distros and I mentioned file manager like Nemo, Dolphin etc and I mentioned that exactly this is my problem: how to determine what file manager is in use (as there are, like you said, different desktop environments). Should've mentioned that it's a GUI application, so no need to think about running it on Linux console only. And anyway ``xdg-open`` does the trick for Linux, so the problem is solved.

Comment: @GenerationLost, everything is clear from your post... even your comment above clarifies it more.... but anyway, think that all those environments grew all without knowing to each other... so no means for them to be compatible or even share a common protocol to comunicate with them.   If you adapt to Nemo (<-- put there the name you want) you'll have to make Windows a Nemo-compatible application.  There's no plain support for this in standard java development environments (this is the main point of my answer)  so I recommended you to use a file manager written in java.... (continues)

Comment: @GenerationLost (continuation) to be able to work with only one such protocol.  Java has the property of running without few or no modifications in such different environments.  You cannot force a commercial product like windows to be compatible with linux and its different distros.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get the point where you connect Windows and Linux. I do understand the point of Java file managers to be independent, but in my case I really want to work with the systems native file managers. Think of it as, for example, the possibility to open the folder of your current project in Eclipse. It opens the Windows Explorer on a Windows platform, and, for example, Nemo on Linux Mint, which is exactly what I want. Now in Java I can easily determine on what system I'm running on and based on that, open the respective file manager.

Comment: I'm not connecting anything.... You ask for a portable solution (the same api on both environments) and I say there's no common API for both environments.  The main thing is you have several environments with different controlling mechanics.  You have to chances: 1st to develop yourself an api compatible with them all, or 2nd, to use a file manager (I suggested java) that runs in all environments (this was the reason for suggesting) untouched.  That way you have the same interface for all environments... But i'm not connecting Linux with Windows at all.  If you need native file managers...